# Android UDP can't receive from outside LAN

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp

My code can't receive UDP messages from outside my home net. The communication is between Android and Java computer application, with IP inside my LAN (for example 192.168.0.3) the code works, if I put my Java computer application inside my online server (and obviously I changed every IP with external IPs) this doesn't work; Android can send but it can't receive.

Android code :

```
@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
    DatagramSocket socket = null;
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket(25565);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("Ex ", "");
    }
    while (true) {
        try {
            socket.receive(packet);
            String message = new String(packet.getData(), 0,packet.getLength());
            Log.i("message", "" + message);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("IO Ex", "");
        }
        catch (Exception e){
        }
    }
}
```

Java computer application code :
http://pastebin.com/2hVGeP6R

Comment: Try to call the flash() method on the socket after you write some data. This will work like this:
-> send data to the server -> flush  (tells the write is done) -> receive packets.

Comment: @GiorgosOikonomou sorry I don't understand what you mean with "flash()"

Comment: Have you tried your app from another wifi ? Possible that your phone company filter one of these ports (25565 because you use it to receive) ? You can use a tool to watch if your packets are sent ?

Comment: I used multiple wifi with the same result

Answer (score 1):

192.168.0.X is an internal NAT address.  Any network can use it, but it can't be reached from anywhere outside.  You either need to configure your router to pass it through to your PC and hit the router's external IP, or you need a real network address.

Comment: This was an example. 192.168.0.X is changed when the application is inside my online server. This address is inside my home and obviously outside my net it can't be reached.

Comment: Yes, but have you configured your router to transmit data from port 1500 to your PC ? (in udp mode)

Comment: @FLefèvre I tested the server code (in receive mode) on my pc and it worked fine, so the problem is about Android and not the communication

Comment: Again somebody that points to the exact root cause of the problem and you not willing to accept the obvious answer.

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully [this](https://systembash.com/a-simple-java-udp-server-and-udp-client/) example. I suppose you  that you are trying to read and write in the same socket while it is open. In case it not working paste some more code in order to help you

Comment: My Android send to port 8 and receives in 25565, the server receives with port 8 and send to port 25565

Comment: Hum port 8 is inferior to 1024, have you launched your program as super user ? What's your server-side OS ?

Comment: Sorry wrong port, I send over 1500 and receive in 25565