# Android UDP works only inside Home net

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp

I have UDP server and client, my code works inside home with internal IPs such as 192.168.0.X. If I put my code inside my online server with external IP (X.X.X.X) server receives and send but Android can only send and doesn't receive. What is the problem?

**Android send code** :

```
byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
    try {
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(1500);
        InetAddress IP = InetAddress.getByName("My server IP");
        String invia = "I am Android";
        sendData = invia.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket send = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IP, 1500);
        serverSocket.send(send);
    }
```

**Android receive code** :

```
 byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
    try {
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(1600);
        while (true) {
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            String sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData());
            Log.i("FROM SERVER:", "" + sentence);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

**Server code** :

```
   DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(1500);
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
        byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
        while(true)
           {
            /** receive **/
              DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
              serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
              String sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData());
              System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence);


            /** send **/
              InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
              int port = receivePacket.getPort();
              sentence = "I am PC";
              sendData = sentence.getBytes();
              DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 1600);
              serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
           }
```

Comment: Have you already forwarded the port (1500) for UDP in your router configuration? It must be forwarded for both the Android device and the Server, since both are listening for data. (Assuming both are connected to an access point)

Comment: With a PC client the connection works so it isn't a router problem but an Android issue I think

Comment: Are you saying that two PC clients running on different PCs can communicate just fine using the posted code?

Comment: @Nicklas Exactly, if I test Android code in a PC the code works and I can receive, with Android not. I don't know if there are different ways to get it, Java is the same so I can't understand how to fix

Comment: sockets are bidirectional your android should send and receive using the same socket otherwise your NATPAT router will not allow the packets in from the server.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck I used 2 differents sockets, one to receive and one to send, however this doesn't change anything because the code tested in a PC works so I can't see relations with port/socket

Comment: It is a huge difference read my comment on NATPAT. A NATPAT router is going to work as a firewall it only allows replies to a port that was used previously to send. That is not the case with port 1600.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck Maybe I am missing what are you talking about, I tested this system inside my home and it worked fine so NATPAT is used only for exterior connections ? Should I use the same port?

Comment: you should read about NATPAT if you want to understand why it does not work and you should change your code to make use of 1 socket iso 2.

Answer (score 0):

Why does it not work externally, yet it does locally ?
You have to understand NATPAT.
Even running a webserver on your home pc will not work. 
When you browse with your browser, you are taking initiative and send a GET to a server using its IP@ and port. Your local IP@ behind the NATPAT router is not unique across the internet, it is unique only behind your router. So your local ip@ of your pc cannot be used to talk to the server. So your router is going to build an internal table based on your local ip@ and local port and a port he allocates himself, he then forwards your request to the webserver you want to talk to but using your public ip@ and that allocated port. when the server replies he is going to reply to your public ip@ and that allocated port. Your NATPAT router sees the reply and know ah it is a reply on that allocated port, it looks in his internal table and forwards to the local ip@ and local port that he remembered in his lookup table.

If you host a server behind a NAT PAT router, you cannot get any incoming messages to your webserver because the table is empty.

And that is the problem with your android listening on port 1600. He never sent anything on that port and ip@ so your router does not know for whom it is.

It works locally because then all your local ip@ are used that your DHCP enabled router has assigned to your devices. And there is never any translation needed to the public IP@ that your ISP has provided you with.

Read this : 
http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/Port-Address-Translation-PAT

and this :
Following is an illustration. Let's say the ISP Public IP address is 3.12.62.154. The objective is to run public-accessible web server that run on standard protocol TCP port 80 (the web port). The local network Private Subnet is 10.0.0.0/24 where the server IP address is 10.0.0.10. For the public access, the 10.0.0.10 will be PAT-ed to the 3.12.62.154 on TCP port 80.

When users on the Internet try to connect to the public web server, those users connect to the 3.12.62.154 IP address and not to the 10.0.0.10 IP address. The reason is that on the Internet, the web server is seen as the 3.12.62.154 IP address. The 10.0.0.10 IP address is only seen within local LAN.

from here : http://www.dslreports.com/faq/13449

If you don't understand any of this, stop trying, start reading instead.

Comment: I think you are missing the point, I don't have problems in communication from server to my own home. If I use the code in a PC the code works and I send and receive from/to server. If I use the code inside Android the receive function will never get any kind of message

Comment: You are missing the point. You clearly say : 'Android can only send and doesn't receive.' your android is listening on port 1600 without ever having sent anything on that port. Therefore it will not ever receive anything from outside your local network.

Comment: This is basically the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29439032/android-udp-cant-receive-from-outside-lan. You cannot have a server running behind a NAT-PAT router ie your local router or modem!

Comment: I am not understanding again; you are talking about communications, so what you are doing is explaining how the communication works but I don't have communication problem. If I copy and paste android code in Eclipse and run the code in my PC it works fine. If what are you talking about is the issue, why does the communication between my PC and my online server works? If the client code is the same in the same network it should be fine in both, PC and Android but it works only in a PC

Comment: if you don't have a communication problem then what do you have ? You say 'Android can only send and doesn't receive. What is the problem?' well that is a communication problem caused by PAT. It cannot receive on port 1600 because it never sent anything on that port. How many times do I have to tell you and when are you going to start listening.

Comment: I wrote more times that the code tested in a PC works and in Android doesn't work, I don't know what is the problem this is what I would know, the communication works from and to my home/onlineserver but the code doesn't work in Android. You can test the code if you have an online server, only paste and copy and you will see that in you pc the code works but in your Android it doesn't work

Comment: Your android cannot receive anything from outside your LAN. It can only receive on that port from within your LAN. And this for reasons I explained numerous times. You cannot run a server behind a NATPAT router.

Comment: I will try to explain :  online server(with java code x) -> PC (with java code y) works, online server (with java code x) -> android (with java code y) doesn't work. both android and PC are connected via Wireless in the same home

Comment: By using just 1 socket. the Android sends to a server outside your local network. that server receives using a single socket and replies on the same socket. Your android will receive on the same socket as well. lose a socket on the server and lose one on the client. And it will work. Sockets are bidirectional. Only the server needs a dedicated port, the android does not.

Comment: I tested the App using the same port to send and receive and it didn't work

Comment: You can find the code up to the page, the code I posted is the entire code without calls

Comment: I only see your wrong code here. Anyway you have to close this question and ask a new one. I answered why you cannot have communication from outside towards your android who is listening on port 1600.

Comment: I can't post multiple questions, why do you see wrong code?

Comment: because it listens to port 1500 and 1600, that is wrong code that won't work. show the code that uses bidirectional use of sockets. and you can create more than one question. close this one and post a new one. This one has an answer.